# Set of functions that form a basis for a Topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following statement: Define $X=\lbrace f| f: [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]\text{ is a function}\rbrace$. For each subset $A$ of $[0,1]$, define
\begin{equation}
B_A=\lbrace f\in X|f(x)=0, \forall x \in A \rbrace.
\end{equation}
Prove that the set $B=\lbrace B_A|A \subseteq [0,1]\rbrace$ is a basis for a topology on $X$.

I tried doing the following: let $f \in X$ with $f \in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$. Then I need to prove that there is a basis element $B_A$ in $B$ such that $f \in B_A \subseteq B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$. I got stucked in here: if $f \in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$ then
\begin{equation}
f(x)=0, \forall x\in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}.
\end{equation}
How can I proceed from here? Only hints, not answers, please.

Comment: Hint: I think there is an $A$ such that $B_A = B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$, which, admittedly, usually doesn't happen for a basis. (I haven't worked this all out and I do have a slight nagging feeling I've missed something, but you did just ask for hints.....)

Comment: I know that that I need to find an $A$ such that $f \in B_A \subseteq B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$. If $f \in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$. But I don't have any idea of how to find such $A$. The only thing that got to my mind is to restrict $f$ to a continuous function whose domain is a subset $A$ of $A_1\cap A_2$. Am I right about this? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't think that's true because $A_1 \cup A_2$ is not a subset of its intersection. Or maybe I'm missing something in the definition of the given set $B_A$.

Comment: Yes, but thinking about that, now I can see that it is not possible that $B_{A_1 \cup A_2}\subseteq B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$.

Comment: FYI if you want to respond to an answer you should use the "Add a comment" link underneath the answer, not create a whole new answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If a map $f$ vanishes on $A_1$ and $A_2$, on which minimal subset (for the inclusion order) does $f$ vanishes?

*Note: you also have to prove that the base elements cover $X$.*

Answer (score 1):

By the definitions, for all $A_1,A_2$ we have: $$B_{A_1 \cup A_2} = B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$$

> **Proof** If $f \in B_{A_1 \cup A_2}$ then for all $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$ we have $f(x)=0$ and so in particular this holds for all $x \in A_1$ and $x \in A_2$ (which are subsets of the union), so $x$ is in the right hand side; and conversely, if $f \in B_{A_1} \cap B_{A_2}$ we have both that $f \in B_{A_1}$ so $f(x)= 0$ for all $x \in A_1$ and also $f \in B_{A_2}$ so that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in A_2$ as well, and it follows that $f(x)=0$ on $A_1 \cup A_2$.QED

Finally note that $B_\emptyset= X$, voidly.